# Which triangulated categories are subcategories of compact objects "somewhere"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, triangulated-categories

Let $T$ be a small triangulated category. Under which conditions there exists a triangulated category $B$ closed with respect to (small) coproducts such that $T$ fully embedds into the subcategory of compact objects of $B$ (I don't need this embedding to be an equivalence; yet if some $B$ of this sort exists then one can always "shrink" it so that its subcategory of compact objects will become the Karoubi envelope of $T$)?

I would conjecture that such a category $B$ exists for any $T$; yet does there exist any way to prove this? What is the largest class of small triangulated categories for which this statement is known?

I suspect that the proof should be "known" whenever some "enhancement" exists for $T$; yet any comments or references would be very welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know of an answer for a general triangulated category (non-topological triangulated categories are very unusual), but as soon as you ask for some more structure the thesis follows very quickly.

Let us suppose that $T$ is the homotopy category of some stable ∞-category $C$ (that is, that $T$ is a topological triangulated category in the sense of Schwede ([arXiv:1201.0899](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0899)) ). Then the idempotent completion (sometimes called the Karoubi envelope) of $C$ is the category of compact object for the stable ∞-category $Ind(C)$ by lemma 5.4.2.4 in Lurie's *Higher Topos Theory*, so the idempotent completion of $T$ is the category of compact objects of the homotopy category of $Ind(C)$.

The fact that $Ind(C)$ is stable (and so its homotopy category is triangulated) is proposition 1.1.3.6 in Lurie's *Higher Algebra*.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you (sorry for my ignorance): can all triangulated categories that admit some sort of an "enhancement" be presented as stable $ \infty$ categories?

Comment: @MikhailBondarko I cannot vouch for all sort of "enhancements", but a stable ∞-category is, roughly speaking, a triangulated category enriched in spectra; so all dg-enhancements should be special cases of it (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2587).

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Another reference that might be useful is Construction 1.3.1.6 in *Higher Algebra*, that for every dg-category constructs an ∞-category with the same homotopy category. I believe that when the original dg-category was triangulated this ∞-category will be automatically stable.

Comment: Thank you! So, you essentially confirm my guess. I wonder whether there exist arguments that are quite distinct from "take a enhancement for $T$ and consider ind-objects for it".

Comment: @MikhailBondarko I very much doubt that a given triangulated category has a stable $\infty$ category associated to it. The example of Muro-Schwede-Strickland "Triangulated categories without models" should be a counterexample. I believe the obstructions they find are present even on the $\infty$-category level, not just the model category level.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Just had a look at 5.4.2.4, and it says C needs to be small. Does that cause any issue? I know Lurie sometimes increases Grothendieck universe to pretend large things are small, but wouldn't that also change the meaning of "compact" and of "small coproducts" in Mikhail's question? How would you argue that 5.4.2.4 still applies even if the word "small" is dropped?

Comment: @DavidWhite The topological triangulated categories are precisely those that can be enhanced to a stable ∞-category, so the categories in Muro-Schwede-Strickland indeed do not come from a stable ∞-category. Also, unless I am mistaken in the OP there's the hypothesis that $T$ is small. Otherwise you have to change universes, as you say. This creates some problems because it changes which triangulated categories are cocomplete, and I believe it makes the question itself ill-posed.

Comment: Yes, $T$ is small in my question. Also, I would be satisfied with any $B$ satisfying my conditions; no "enhancements" for it are necessary.